# Password saving for API usage (php and mysql)

Tags: php, security, password-protection, password-encryption, password-hash

I am using [Instagram API by mgp25](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API).

Here, you can gain access to the IG api via "logging in": the API (in php) requires a password and account id to be in **plain text** format when gaining the access.

**Here is the setup that I have:**

I have a site where there are users and the site has IG API integration. These users can input their Instagram User/Password (not the user info to log into the site) to gain access to the API.

However, these API only accepts plain text for password (since the password will then be verified within the IG server).

**Problem:**

The problem that I am having is the password security. Obviously I can't store the IG password as plain text, but if I hash them, it can't be used to login to the API either (as it is one-way only).

**Methods:** 
I can only think of encrypting the password (not hashed) and decrypt them when needed. However, I can see a few issues with that approach as well.

I wanted to ask you guys what you guys think of the best way to address this issue.

(**note**. The official IG API has some limitation and are only allowing official business partners to have more functions which I need them. So the API by mgp25 is the only viable option at the moment).

Comment: Encrypting the passwords like you suggest is the same as taping the key to the back of the padlock, and is basically the same as plaintext. You're not going to be able to get around that. I would second @flyjoe12's suggestion of not storing it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could require the password only once. The private API will save the cookies / session forever and you do not need to do a login again.

So this way you don't have to store passwords and, if for some reason the user is logged out, then you ask for password again. Does it make sense?

Comment: That makes a total sense! =) Thanks! That will take care of so much headache =) Thanks buddy!